# Domain-Range graph not displayed in GraphDB Free ver. 8.5

Tags: rdf, rdfs, graphdb

I loaded the following statements into an OWL-Horst repository:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/owlim#>.
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:Foo a owl:Class .
:Bar a owl:Class .
:p a owl:ObjectProperty .
:f a :Foo .
:b a :Bar .
:f :p :b .
```

But I cannot visualize the [Domain-Range chart](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/quick-start-guide.html?highlight=domain%20range#domain-range-graph). I get the message "No Domain-Range graph available for '<Class_Name>'.

What is wrong with my graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[a :Foo] :p [a :Bar]` does not entail `:p rdfs:domain :Foo; rdfs:range :Bar`. This should be an RDFS-level rule, and [there is no](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#patterns-of-rdfs-entailment-informative) such a rule.

You should say explicitely:

```
:p rdfs:domain :Foo .
:p rdfs:range :Bar .
```

Then you'll get something like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7NCf.png).

By the way, constructing domain-range graph, GraphDB performs the following query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?prop ?propertyType ?objectPropClass (?c != :Bar as ?implicit) {
    {
        :Bar rdfs:subClassOf ?c
    }
    UNION
    {
        VALUES ?c { :Bar }
    }
    {
        ?prop a owl:ObjectProperty ;
            rdfs:domain ?c ;
            rdfs:range ?objectPropClass ;
            rdfs:domain ?objectPropClass ;
            rdfs:range ?c .
        BIND ("objectLeftRight" as ?propertyType)
        BIND (1 as ?order)
    }
    UNION
    {
        ?prop a owl:ObjectProperty ;
            rdfs:domain ?c ;
            rdfs:range ?objectPropClass .
        BIND ("objectRight" as ?propertyType)
        BIND (2 as ?order)
    }
    UNION
    {
        ?prop a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
            rdfs:domain ?c .
        BIND ("datatype" as ?propertyType)
        BIND (3 as ?order)
    }
    UNION
    {
        ?prop a owl:ObjectProperty ;
            rdfs:domain ?objectPropClass ;
            rdfs:range ?c .
        BIND ("objectLeft" as ?propertyType)
        BIND (4 as ?order)
    }
    FILTER(?objectPropClass != :Bar || ?propertyType != "objectRight"
                                    && ?propertyType != "objectLeft")
} ORDER BY ?order ?objectPropClass ?prop
```

**Update**

> ...after taking a quick look at the docs, I believed that GraphDB did a kind of analysis based on the actual use of the properties with classes instances.

- It seems that the [Class relationships](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/exploring-data.html#class-relationships) view provides such information in the left panel.
- Also, you can create [your own](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/quick-start-guide.html#create-your-own-visual-graph) Visual Graph configuration. I was able to `CONSTRUCT` this image:

  [image: custom visual graph]

Comment: Got it. I knew that domain and range statements are not inferred, but after taking a quick look at the docs, I believed that GraphDB did a kind of analysis based on the actual use of the properties with classes instances, irrespective of explicit `rdfs:domain` and `rdfs:range` statements. Thanks!